# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED Isn't Getting Resolve Even with Correct DNS Settings

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just transferred the domain from Google Domains to Cloud Domains on Google Cloud. Now I am getting a `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` issue even with correct DNS setup.

I also set up a Cloud DNS with DNSSEC on.

I switch the domain from Google Domains to Cloud DNS.

The IP address is correct since when I put it in the browser, it shows the website.

Is there some type of **DELAY**? From transfer?

[image]

Comment: Most likely you have not waited long enough. There are online sites to test your domain and help you figure out what is wrong. Your site is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive troubleshooting, I felt like I was going insane. Everything was correct but still showing nothing even after giving acceptable time for propagation. But now everything works. Here are potential sources of the issue:

- Time for propagation (may take a few mins to set in)
- **Browser Cache** (clear all sites and history)
- **DNS Cache** (clear using https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache)
- **Router Cache** (yes your router has cache that can cause this problem)
- OS Cache (on your computer, clear using terminal commands)

In my case, I had router cache issue. The way to clear this is to simply connect to another router (mobile data not wifi for example) or to reset the router by holding reset for 10 seconds. You can test this by clearing your phones browser cache and then attempting to connect via mobile data.

**Side Note:**
Propagation may take time. And this is most likely the issue.

Comment: If your router cache was the issue, that means at some point your incorrectly configured your DNS server. You made a DNS query from your network and the router cached that response. When working with DNS, if you make a mistake, it can take hours to days to self-correct after you correct the DNS server. How long is determined by TTLs and Negative Caching. Note: you should not be using your router for DNS resolution. If your network was correctly configured, you would not have had the router issue.

Comment: @JohnHanley so there is an issue with the router? At some point when I was configuring, I reloaded the page and it set the router to cache some type of permanent response?

Comment: Not the router. You configured the DNS server wrong and the router cached that wrong data.